# If the first field doesn't exists in a table then look at a different field in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to select a field from a table and if that field doesn't exist then select a different field from the same table? example:

```
SELECT MY_FIELD from MY_TABLE
```

> error: "MY_FIELD": invalid identifier

is there any way to check if it exists and if it does then use that field for the query, if it doesn't exist then use example:

```
SELECT my_field2 from client.
```

My problem is
I am writing a report that will be used on two databases, but the field names on occasion can be named slightly different depending on the database.

Comment: What about creating views? This way you query the views instead of tables, avoiding the issue of variable column names. Another way could be dynamic SQL, but you would need PLSQL and not only plain SQL.

Answer (score 3):

What you really need to do is talk to your management / development leads about why the different databases are not harmonized.  But, since this is a programming site, here is a programming answer using dynamic SQL.

As has been pointed out, you could create views in the different databases to provide yourself with a harmonized layer to query from.  If you are unable to create views, you can do something like this:

```
create table test ( present_column NUMBER );

insert into test select rownum * 10 from dual connect by rownum <= 5;


    declare
      l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
      BEGIN
        OPEN l_rc FOR 'SELECT missing_column FROM test';
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
          OPEN l_rc FOR 'SELECT present_column FROM test';
      END;
      -- This next only works in 12c and later
      -- In earlier versions, you've got to process l_rc on your own.
      DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(l_rc);
    end;
```

This is inferior to the other solutions (either harmonizing the databases or creating views).  For one thing, you get no compile time checking of your queries this way.

Answer (score 1):

That won't compile, so - I'd say not. You might try with dynamic SQL which reads contents of the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and create `SELECT` statement on-the-fly.

Depending on *reporting tool* you use, that might (or might not) be possible. For example, Apex offers (as reports's source) a function that returns query, so you might use it there.

I'd suggest a simpler option - create **views** on both databases which have unified column names, so that your report always selects from the view and works all the time. For example:

```
-- database 1:
create view v_client as
  select client_id id,
         client_name name
  from your_table;

-- database 2:
create view v_client as
  select clid id,
         clnam name
  from your_table;

-- reporting tool:
select id, name
from v_client;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single SQL statement using `DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML`, but it gets messy.  It would probably be cleaner to use dynamic SQL or a view, but there are times when it's difficult to create supporting objects.

Sample table:

```
--Create either table.
create table my_table(my_field1 number);
insert into my_table values(1);
insert into my_table values(2);

create table my_table(my_field2 number);
insert into my_table values(1);
insert into my_table values(2);
```

Query:

```
--Get the results by converting XML into rows.
select my_field
from
(
    --Convert to an XMLType.
    select xmltype(clob_results) xml_results
    from
    (
        --Conditionally select either MY_FIELD1 or MY_FIELD2, depending on which exists.
        select dbms_xmlgen.GetXML('select my_field1 my_field from my_table') clob_results
        from user_tab_columns
        where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
            and column_name = 'MY_FIELD1'
            --Stop transformations from running the XMLType conversion on nulls.
            and rownum >= 1
        union all
        select dbms_xmlgen.GetXML('select my_field2 my_field from my_table') clob_results
        from user_tab_columns
        where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
            and column_name = 'MY_FIELD2'
            --Stop transformations from running the XMLType conversion on nulls.
            and rownum >= 1
    )
    --Only convert non-null values.
    where clob_results is not null
)
cross join
xmltable
(
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    passing xml_results
    columns
        my_field number path 'MY_FIELD'
);
```

Results:

```
MY_FIELD
--------
1
2
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c73de/1) a SQL Fiddle if you want to see it running.